# Protobuf3: How to describe map of repeated string?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

The [Official documentation about map type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps) says:

> `map<key_type, value_type> map_field = N;`
>
> ...where the key_type can be any integral or string type (so, any
>   scalar type except for floating point types and bytes). The value_type
>   can be **any type**.

I want to define a `map<string, repeated string>` field, but it seems illegal on my `libprotoc 3.0.0`, which complains `Expected ">"`. So I wonder if there is any way to put repeated string into map.

A Possible workaround could be:

```
message ListOfString {
    repeated string value = 1;
}

// Then define:
map<string, ListOfString> mapToRepeatedString = 1;
```

But `ListOfString` here looks redundant.

Comment: Just checking the basics :) Have you set `syntax = "proto3";`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same need, and got the same error. I do not believe this is possible. Here is the relevant BNF definitions from the language specification.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec

```
messageType = [ "." ] { ident "." } messageName
mapField = "map" "<" keyType "," type ">" mapName "=" fieldNumber [ "["fieldOptions "]" ] ";"
type = "double" | "float" | "int32" | "int64" | "uint32" | "uint64"
  | "sint32" | "sint64" | "fixed32" | "fixed64" | "sfixed32" | "sfixed64"
  | "bool" | "string" | "bytes" | messageType | enumType
messageName = ident
ident = letter { letter | decimalDigit | "_" }
field = [ "repeated" ] type fieldName "=" fieldNumber [ "[" fieldOptions "]" ] ";"
```

"repeated" keyword only appears in the field definition. The map definition requires a "type", which does not include the repeated keyword.

That means there are a few options.

- You could create a wrapper around the repeated value as you indicated.
- There is the older way people defined define maps, which is more burdensome but is equivalent. This is the backwards compatible example from the language guide.

  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

  ```
      message MapFieldEntry {
        key_type key = 1;
        repeated value_type value = 2;
      }
      repeated MapFieldEntry map_field = N;
  ```

  You would need to convert the data to a map yourself, but this should be fairly trivial in most languages. In Java:

  ```
      List<MapFieldEntry> map_field = // Existing list from protobuf.
      Map<key_type, List<value_type>> = map_field.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(kv -> kv.key, kv -> kv.value));
  ```
- Use google.protobuf.ListValue

  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#listvalue

  This is an untyped list collection from their well known types.

Comment: I'm curious why Protobuf has both 'ListValue' and 'repeated'.  Do they not serve the same purpose?  The immediate documentation on 'ListValue' is somewhat sparse.

Comment: @EdwinW
`ListValue` and `repeated` are different.

`ListValue` is an untyped list -- its contents could be anything. `repeated` takes a type and indicates that it is explicitly a list of that type.

Answer (score 14):

I think it should be as follows.

```
message ListOfString {
   repeated string what_ever_name = 1;
}

// Then define:
map<string, ListOfString> what_ever_name = 1;
```

Remember ***what_ever_name*** should be same in both places.

Comment: Why does the field name of `what_ever_name` need to be the same in both places? Isn't it a completely separate type?

Comment: @BigMoney it doesn't have to be. I think it's just how this example is laid out.

Comment: Why _should_ it be the same in both places?